# Swift/Xcode: How do I detect key presses?

Tags: ios, swift

I am wondering how I could detect key presses in Xcode - my goal is to be able to detect when keys are pressed, specifically the space, escape, enter and WASD keys.

**What I have tried**

I have tried pressesBegan, pressesEnded and its other 'variants', and I have also tried keyDown. After looking for 2 hours, the only ways I could find to detect key presses were from the two methods listed above, which don't seem to be working for me.

When using pressesBegan, I tried putting the following code in both the GameViewController.swift file and the AppDelegate.swift file, however it doesn't seem to work:

```
override func pressesBegan(_ presses: Set<UIPress>, with event: UIPressesEvent?) {
    guard let key = presses.first?.key else { return }
    print(key.keyCode)
}
```

The code shows no errors, and even when I put a print file at the very start of the function to see if it is being called it does not give any output.

After this, I tried a keyDown function (in the GameViewController.swift file), however it threw the error "Cannot find type NSEvent in scope". I fixed this error by adding ", NSObject" to the top of the file in the line "class GameViewController: UIViewController {" but that threw the error "Multiple inheritance from classes 'UIViewController' and 'NSObject'". I have looked for about an hour but there are no solutions which match my issue/have not worked for me.

```
import UIKit
```

import SpriteKit
import GameplayKit

class GameViewController: UIViewController {

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    if let view = self.view as! SKView? {
        // Load the SKScene from 'GameScene.sks'
        if let scene = SKScene(fileNamed: "SplashScreen") {
            // Set the scale mode to scale to fit the window
            scene.scaleMode = .aspectFill
            
            // Present the scene
            view.presentScene(scene)
        }
        
        view.ignoresSiblingOrder = true
        
        view.showsFPS = true
        view.showsNodeCount = true
    }
}

override var shouldAutorotate: Bool {
    return true
}

override var supportedInterfaceOrientations: UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    if UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .phone {
        return .allButUpsideDown
    } else {
        return .all
    }
}

override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
    return true
}

override func pressesBegan(_ presses: Set<UIPress>, with event: UIPressesEvent?) {
    guard let key = presses.first?.key else { return }

    switch key.keyCode {
    case .keyboardR:
        print("Roll dice")
    case .keyboardH:
        print("Show help")
    default:
        super.pressesBegan(presses, with: event)
    }
}

override func keyDown(with event: NSEvent) {
    print("a")
}
```

}

If you need any additional things I'll try to get back to you as quick as possible. I'm really sorry if I've missed something extremely obvious like putting it in a different file.

Thank you!

Comment: eggpoison: If I have understood your question properly, are you trying to detect a specific character press in the keyboard?

Comment: iPeter, yes I am.

Answer (score 0):

the `pressesEnd()` method works in the same way; Try to import UIKit first:

```
override func pressesEnded(_ presses: Set<UIPress>, with event: UIPressesEvent?) {
    guard let key = presses.first?.key else { return }

    switch key.keyCode {
    case .keyboardSpacebar:
        print("Continue the quiz…")
    default:
        super.pressesEnded(presses, with: event)
    }
}
```

More can be found at:

https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/uikit/how-to-detect-keyboard-input-using-pressesbegan-and-pressesended

Comment: I've already tried the pressesEnd method, but it didn't seem to detect when I pressed the keyboard. Where should I put the method? I've tried putting it in AppDelegate, GameViewController and the scene in which I'm trying to detect the presses but nothing I've tried works.